# SIGSEGV recovery?

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, x86

I ve got some SSE procedure which zeroes memory in loop,
When pointer is unaligned it raises SIGSEGV which goes 
into my handler. Can I get more info here in such handler
routine, Now I got no info where it was done, can I also
react in some predictible way from it? When I chose to 
ignore it It seemd to me that it should go back and becouse
it was in loop raise SIGSEGV again, (got such behaviour with 
division by zero when where I ignore it it just goes on
further) but it does not work here such way but sadly just 
crashes after ignoring. Can I do some more eleborate recovery here?

EDIT - ADD

in my signal.h (some very old win32 compiler but I use it)
 I have such stuff

```
    /* _SIGCONTEXT contains exception info for WIN32 exceptions that were caught
     and turned into signals.  There will always be three 32-bit parameters
     passed to the user's signal handler.  Unused parameters will be 0.  The
    _PSIGCONTEXT parameter will always be the last (third) parameter.
      */

    typedef struct
     {
      struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD * _pexecptionrecord; /* defined in WINNT.H */
      struct _CONTEXT *          _pcontext;         /* defined in WINNT.H */
      unsigned long              _result;           /* return value for the SEH */
     } _SIGCONTEXT, *_PSIGCONTEXT;

     typedef int sig_atomic_t;   /* Atomic entity type (ANSI) */

     typedef void (*_CatcherPTR)(int);

     #define SIG_DFL ((_CatcherPTR)0)   /* Default action   */
     #define SIG_IGN ((_CatcherPTR)1)   /* Ignore action    */
     #define SIG_ERR ((_CatcherPTR)-1)  /* Error return     */

      //////////////////////////////////
     //skipped  #define SIGABRT  22  
     //         #define SIGFPE  8  .... constants block  here

     int raise(int __sig);

     void (*signal(int __sig, void (*__func)(int) )) (int);
```

Signal Raise are understood for me but how to get to data of SIGCONTEXT or use 'catcher' ?

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible on some operating systems under certain circumstances to catch and handle SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGILL and SIGFPE it's a really bad idea to do anything other than crashing. They indicate a bug in your program that you need to fix, not something you just sweep under the rug.

But in case you really enjoy shooting yourself in the foot and leaving horrible undebuggable and unmaintainable messes that others will have to clean up after you while cursing you and your ancestors while wishing that voodoo worked, have a peek at the documentation for sigaction() and how siginfo_t. They contain at least some parts of what you need.

Comment: hah, I know I should remove tha cause for example zero division, but it is interesting to get more info on such things, - I will check it, If find corelated things I will accept the answer, tnx

Comment: forgot to mention that i am specially intrested in win32, do you know something with that?

Comment: Handling `SIGSEGV` / `SIGBUS` under specific circumstances is desirable and possible; in fact, this is how certain hypervisors and/or system emulators work. The idea is to have e.g. privileged instructions trigger exceptions to make the kernel send `SIGSEGV` to the program, and the signal handler emulate the actual effect (like, a Windows syscall from within the Linux Wine Win32 emulator). Or, in the `SIGBUS` case, use `mmap(...,MAP_NORESERVE)` to allocate address space but deliberately not back it up, so that accesses cause `SIGBUS` and e.g. memory-mapped hardware registers can be emulated.

Comment: @FrankH.This is true. But in case you're doing things like writing a hypervisor, implementing your own userland swapper or implementing an overcommiting allocator on a system without one (IIRC this was how old old vi did memory management), you probably already understand signal delivery mechanisms and how to dig up extra information from them. :)

Comment: @grungefightr I'm sorry. Didn't notice this was about win32. I'm not sure if sigaction exists there or if it's even possible to deal with SEGV there. I seem to recall that the only signal you can really handle on win32 was SIGFPE, but this is a very hazy memory.

Comment: It can handle many, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12(v=vs.71).aspx , but when I do it the only handler form it compile is simple "void signal_handler(int sig)" In somewhat messy signal.h in my compilator there are other defs esecially _SIGCONTEXT with context of err but I do not know how to reach for that